# Why does Indesign repeat the same photo on its own, over and over?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm making a wedding photo book, with deferent photos of course.

When I open the file with Indesign, some of the photos seem to have repeated themselves. I don't know if its because they are all on one layer or because they have the same name.

I first edit them on Photoshop and save them as the same name.

Can anyone tell me why a photo would repeat itself automatically?

Comment: try and relink them through the 'links' panel?

Comment: InDesign links images, doesn't it? Thus if you include `A.jpg` and then overwrite that file with another `A.jpg` the second file will replace the first *in the document as well.* Even if it's possible to force InDesign to include the pics in the file instead of linking [I don't know whether it is or not], you will need to make those images available. It doesn't sound as though you have retained the edited versions at all.

Comment: In short, InDesign does NOT import images (by default at least). If you want two versions of the same image you have provide both images. You can also reference different photoshop layers if you only want to keep only one file.

Comment: Sure thanks Scott anyway the reason they're all the same name is bcoz im using the same photoshop document just to resize them bcoz they're already adited and I don't want to the same photos in defferent sizes.Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the same file names for photos if the photos are different.

Indesign merely *references* external files such as photographs. If you have multiple photos of the same name in the same location, then it's understandable Indesign gets confused. Although, I don't know how you would pull off the same file names in the same location on any computer. Traditionally you are restricted to one name per file per directory on computers.

In short, try not naming the files the same name then relink the photos in Indesign.